# Warning message: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated

Tags: error-handling, phyloseq

I encountered this warning message while changing the row names:

```
Warning message: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.
```

Can anyone please help me to this warning message/error?

Thanks and regards,
DC7

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, I would recommend that you look at the tibble documentation [for working with rownames](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html), where you can use the `column_to_rownames()` to set rownames from variable values in a column.